# How can I load scraped page content to langchain VectorstoreIndexCreator

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I have a function which goes to url and crawls its content (+ from subpages). Then I want to load text content to langchain `VectorstoreIndexCreator()` . How can I do it via loader? I could not find any suitable loader in `langchain.document_loaders`. Should I use BaseLoader for it? How?

My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import openai
from langchain.document_loaders.base import Document
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator


def get_company_info_from_web(company_url: str, max_crawl_pages: int = 10, questions=None):

    # goes to url and get urls 
    links = get_links_from_page(company_url)

    # get_text_content_from_page goes to url and yields text, url tuple
    for text, url in get_text_content_from_page(links[:max_crawl_pages]): 
        # add text content (string) to index
        # loader????

    index= VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_documents([Document(page_content=content, metadata={"source": url})])

    # Finally, query the vector database:
    DEFAULT_QUERY = f"What does the company do? Who are key people in this company? Can you tell me contact information?"
    query = questions or DEFAULT_QUERY
    logger.info(f"Query: {query}")
    result = index.query_with_sources(query)

    logger.info(f"Result:\n {result['answer']}")
    logger.info(f"Sources:\n {result['sources']}")

    return result['answer'], result['sources']
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the [WebBaseLoader](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/document_loaders/integrations/web_base) which usages `BeautifulSoup` behind the scene to parse the data.

See the below sample:

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader

loader = WebBaseLoader(your_url)
scrape_data = loader.load()
```

you can do multiple web pages by passing an array of URLs like below:

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader

loader = WebBaseLoader([your_url_1, your_url_2])
scrape_data = loader.load()
```

And to load multiple web pages concurrently, you can use the `aload()` method.

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader

loader = WebBaseLoader([your_url_1, your_url_2])
scrape_data = loader.aload() # <-------- here
```

You may encounter some issues with loading concurrently if you already have a running asynio event loop which will throw an error something like `"nested event loop error"` or `"RuntimeError: This event loop is already running"` something like that. You can resolve this issue by using [nest_asyncio](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio) library which is a patch to allow nested event loops. See the sample below:

```py
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

loader = WebBaseLoader([your_url_1, your_url_2])
scrape_data = loader.aload()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use it but I am getting `ValueError: Expected metadata value to be a str, int, or float, got None` when my code inside function body is 

    `links = get_links_from_page(valid_url)`

    `loader = WebBaseLoader(links)`


    `index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader]) #here is the error`


    `# Finally, query the vector database:`

    `DEFAULT_QUERY = f"What does {company_name} do?" `

    `query = questions or DEFAULT_QUERY`
    `result = index.query(query)` (not possible to better format in comments :/ )